# how i can apply which.min function conditionally

Tags: r

I want to create a column in dataframe  and populate minimum value in the data frame in column A condition is met :

```
**Sample data** 
Variable value
A         10
A         20
A         30
B         5
B         60
B         70
```

**Expected Result :**

```
Variable value   NewColumn
A         10     min
A         20     between min to 20
A         30     between 21 to 30
B         5      min
B         60     between 50 to 60
```

Is there any easy way to achieve this ?

Comment: what is `between 20 to 30`?

Comment: It will be easy to spot and flag the `min` per group, but I'm not sure I get the philosophy you apply to the rest of the values. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I am trying to create a new column and distinguish it in dataframe based on  following criterias : a. if value is min based b. if value is between 20 and min, if value between 20 to 30 and so on

Comment: So, you want to get min if it is the min value of a factor, and between which two Tens is the value. Is it that ?

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: `DF %>% dplyr::group_by(Variable) %>% dplyr::mutate(New =  as.character(cut(value, value)))`

Comment: `data.table::setDT(DF)[, .( value, as.character(cut(value, value))), by = Variable]`

Comment: Andre Elrico  thank you it seems very concise but how i can pick first break to be min value is still a challenge to me.

Answer (score 1):

The output in the question seems inconsistent since sometimes the lower bound is 10 less than the upper bound and other times is 9 less.  We have defined it to be 9 less and if min is 9 or 10 below the upper bound write `min` instead of the lower bound.

Now, define a function which inputs a vector `x` and categorizes it using `ave` to apply it separately to each group.  No packages are used.

```
categorize <- function(x) {
  upper <- 10 * ceiling(x / 10)
  lower <- ifelse(upper-9 == min(x) | upper-10 == min(x), "min", upper-9)
  ifelse(x == min(x), "min", paste("between", lower, "to", upper))
}

transform(DF, New = ave(value, Variable, FUN = categorize))
```

giving:

```
  Variable value               New
1        A    10               min
2        A    20 between min to 20
3        A    30  between 21 to 30
4        B     5               min
5        B    60  between 51 to 60
6        B    70  between 61 to 70
```

### Note

The input `DF` used, in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
Variable value
A         10
A         20
A         30
B         5
B         60
B         70"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```